# IBM Worklight Splash Screen

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, splash-screen

I Place my custom splash screen(file Name:splash.9.png) in 
/android/native/res/drawable..

But when iam exporting as .apk file using eclipse. after exporting in .apk file location mentioned above default IBM splash screen .png will be replaced.

How can i do this?

Comment: You need to delete the worklight-provided splash image in the native folder. Replace it with the same filename but with your image. You then need to build your project and export it.

Comment: 1. i have deleted splash.9.png from appName/android/native/res/drawable folder and added my custom splash.9.png. 2. when i exported as .apk  and i opened .apk file using winzip and went upto drawable folder then open splash.9.png but its showing IBM splash screen.

Comment: What are you asking then?

Comment: 1. i have deleted splash.9.png from appName/android/native/res/drawable folder and added my custom splash.9.png. 2. when i exported as .apk and i opened .apk file using winzip and went upto drawable folder then open splash.9.png but its showing IBM splash screen

Comment: Did you make sure to Run on Worklight Development Server and only then export your apk?

Comment: When Iam created android environment it will going to create new project with ProjectNameappNameAndroid . on project rightclick export as .apk and following further steps.

Comment: Yes, but you must change the file in the Worklight project > native folder and then RE-build the project for the changes to move into the generated Android project BEFORE you export the APK

Comment: yes in generated android project its showing my custom splash.9.png but after exporting .apk its not refeleting and when i run android project using android application in that also its showing IBM splash screen but when i directly install the application throgh USB cable into mobile then its showing my custom splash.9.png image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a weird one... I have indeed experienced this as well.

To solution is, in Eclipse go to `Project > Clean...`.
Select the project.

After cleaning it, proceed with the export. You should see the new image (also when running the app in the Android Emulator).